# Oracle SELECT FOR UPDATE ignoring already locked records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, locking, dao

We have a high transactional, high concurrent java system accessing data stored on an Oracle 11.g instance. Our system is deployed on multiple Websphere 8.5 application servers.
The concurrent access to the data is performed by different transactional processes running in different threads.

Consider the table below whose records should be processed  following the rules:

1. The ID is just a sequence number indicating which record was created first.
2. There is not a requested that IDs are consecutive numbers but it is sure record with ID = 1 was inserted before record with ID > 1
3. The records with the same BUSINESS_ID must be processed in the ID order (e.g. for BUSINESS_ID=1 the processing order must be ID = 1, 2, 4)
4. If a record with a BUSINESS_ID is actually being processed by a thread no record with the same BUSINESS_ID should be processed by a different thread.
5. It is OK for a different thread to start processing the record with the smallest ID that has a BUSINESS_ID that is not currently being processed by any other thread.
6. When a processing a record is finished the record gets deleted from the table.

ID  BUSINESS_ID

```
==============
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       1
5       3
6       3
7       2
```

To create that test data you can run these:

```
create table test (id number, business_id number);
insert into test values (1, 1);
insert into test values (2, 1);
insert into test values (3, 2);
insert into test values (4, 1);
insert into test values (5, 3);
insert into test values (6, 3);
insert into test values (7, 2);
commit;
```

To simulate three threads you can open a separate database session for each thread. In this case a processing flow could be like below:

1. Thread A:  looks for work and gets record ID = 1 (the smallest ID of a record BUSINESS_ID not currently being processed) This will lock record ID=1
2. Thread B:  looks for work and gets record ID = 3 (BUSINESS_ID = 1 currently being processed by thread A prevents thread B for picking up record ID = 2)
3. Thread C:  looks for work and gets record ID = 5 (BUSINESS_ID = 1 and 2 are currently being processed by threads A and B)
4. Thread A: finishes work and deletes record ID =1 and commits the work.
   Thread A: looks for work and gets record ID = 2
5. And so on ...

My idea is to use SELECT FOR UPDATE to mark a record for processing and when the work is finished to delete and commit the selected record.

Implementing this logic with a stored procedure will work however our approach is to keep the business logic at the middle tier level in the java code rather than at the database level.

Can you see a way to achieve this just by running SQLs as opposed to implementing it in a stored procedure?

So in short what I am after is a SELECT FOR UPDATE of the record having the smallest ID with a BUSINESS_ID that does not belong to any other locked records in that table.

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, why can't you execute your select in java?  You don't state how records get inserted into this table.

Comment: Well that is my question. What would be that SQL?
Some other transactional processes insert those records with the ID field coming from a sequence.

Comment: You need to go through this: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2060739900346201280